# How to convert C# output of DateTime to "Days Remaining" using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I am running an app on .net forms that displays a DateTime output that we're pulling from a database. It's displayed as an expiration date.

```
public DateTime DATE_EXPIRES { get; set; }
public String DATE_EXPIRES_STR { get; set; }

        public void FromRow(Hashtable row)
        {
            try
            {
                DATE_EXPIRES = row.ContainsKey("DATE_EXPIRES") && row["DATE_EXPIRES"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(row["DATE_EXPIRES"]) : default(DateTime);
                DATE_EXPIRES_STR = DATE_EXPIRES.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SCORM.Error += ex.Message + "\r\n";
            }
        }
```

My goal is, instead of displaying an expiration date, to display a "Days Left" and calculate the difference between today, and the date displayed and show the user "55 Days Left", and so forth.

My question is regarding whether I need to convert and display using C#, or display the date as is, and let JavaScript look at the date, calculate the time remaining and then output the days remaining, instead of displaying the actual expiry date?

**How it currently looks**
[image]

**My intended look**
[image]

Comment: May I know how does the datetime string look like when you pass the data over in JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `momentjs` to calculate day remaining and each tr to convert values like this.

You don't update C# code, only add javascript code in document ready for convert Expires column.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").each(function (index, item) {
      if (index == 0) {
        $(item).find('th').eq(1).text('Days Remaining');
      } else {
        let date = $(item).find('td').eq(1).text();
        var eventdate = moment(date, "MMMM DD, YYYY");
        var todaysdate = moment();
        days = eventdate.diff(todaysdate, 'days');
        $(item).find('td').eq(1).text(days + ' Days Left')
      }
    })
  });
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Expires</th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td>Course 1</td>
    <td>June 24, 2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td>Course 2</td>
    <td>June 24, 2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```